# Como fazer um script executar automaticamente?

Tags: php, newsletter

Estou fazendo um *script* para envio de *emails* à assinantes, como um *newsletter*, porém necessito que ele execute automaticamente e que esta execução seja de hora em hora.

Como meu sistema operacional é o *Windows* e inicialmente quero testar este *script* localmente, pesquisei e vi que deveria ser agendada uma tarefa que faria a execução deste *script*, mas não faço ideia de como fazê-lo.

Além disto, devo fazer com que a cada hora o *script* envie 100 *emails*, ou seja, se houver 300 assinantes, na primeira hora o *script* enviará 100 *emails* e sua execução será interrompida, na segunda hora a execução é retomada e enviados mais 100 *emails* e assim sucessivamente, até todos os assinantes receberem os *emails*.

Até agora consegui enviar todos, mas não estou conseguindo fazer esse controle do número de *emails* enviados por hora, gostaria de que me ajudassem, dando uma dica ou ideia de como fazê-lo.

Agradeço

Comment: não seria o caso de uma flag? envia 100 e marca como enviado + envia mais 100 e marca como enviado, ao final de todos os envios a flag é zerada para a próxima remessa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para enviar em 100 em 100 você terá que programar isso no script que você usa, para selecionar 100 registros. Em windows não sei fazer isso, mas recomendo você usar Linux (Hospedagem) e usar a opção CRON que tem no PHPMyadmin. Lá você irá programar em quantas em quantas horas você quer enviar e deverá colocar a o caminho do arquivo que deverá executar, ex: /home/public_html/files/arquivo.php