# Impedir que usuário cadastre 3 vezes na mesma semana

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para agendamento de reservas de locais e equipamentos para os usuários cadastrados nesse sistema, que no caso são professores, reservarem tais itens para suas aulas: o professor loga no sistema, escolhe os equipamentos e o local e escolhe uma data e um horário livre para usufruir dessa reserva.

Eu estou tentando fazer com que um mesmo usuário não possa fazer reservas mais de 3 vezes em uma mesma semana, sendo essa semana de segunda-feira a sábado. Eu tentei fazer com diversas funções do PHP e em SQL (MySQL) mas não obtive nenhum sucesso.

Aqui está a estrutura da minha tabela SQL:

```
 CREATE TABLE agend_reservas (
  ID_AGENDAMENTO bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  LOCAL1  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  LOCAL2  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  LOCAL3  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  LOCAL4  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  LOCAL5  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  LOCAL6  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  LOCAL7  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  LOCAL8  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  LOCAL9  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  LOCAL10 int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  LOCAL11 int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  LOCAL12 int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  LOCAL13 int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  EQUIPAMENTO1  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  EQUIPAMENTO2  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  EQUIPAMENTO3  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  EQUIPAMENTO4  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  EQUIPAMENTO5  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  EQUIPAMENTO6  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  EQUIPAMENTO7  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  EQUIPAMENTO8  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  EQUIPAMENTO9  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  EQUIPAMENTO10 int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  INTERNET varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  RESERVADO_PARA varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  RESERVA_PARA_DATA date NOT NULL,
  HORA_INICIO time NOT NULL,
  HORA_FIM time NOT NULL,
  RESERVADO_NA_DATA date NOT NULL,
  OBSERVACAO text
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Aqui está a estrutura da minha tabela, o campo `RESERVA_PARA_DATA` é a data que o usuário irá usar a reserva, o campo `RESERVADO_NA_DATA` é a data atual do servidor que o usuário efetuou a reserva - essa data não importa - e o campo `RESERVADO_PARA` é o nome do usuário que está reservando.

Comment: Um count no banco de acordo com seus critérios dentro da semana em questão já não lhe ajuda ?

Comment: Eu não estou conseguindo saber o que usar no where para poder filtrar em que semana deve ocorrer a verificação.

Comment: Adicione na pergunta a estrutura da sua tabela. Sem isso fica difícil ajudar. Já adiantando provavelmente você deve ter um campo Data na sua tabela com as suas reservas, com isso basta fazer um `count` dentro da semana atual que irá retornar a quantidade de registros encontrados. Com isso valide se o retorno é maior que X vezes.

Comment: @LucasBarbosaFonseca Adicione o código, para ficar mais fácil de ajudarmos

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme eu já havia comentado na sua pergunta, se você fazer um `count` na sua tabela **agend_reservas** já vai lhe atender.

No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
$datenow = date('Y-m-d');// Data atual

$first = (new DateTime($datenow))->modify('Last Monday')->format('Y-m-d');
$last = (new DateTime($datenow))->modify('Next Sunday')->format('Y-m-d');

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM agend_reservas 
            WHERE   reserva_para_data BETWEEN '$first' AND '$last'
            AND     reservado_para = '$usuario_resevando'";

$result = mysqli_query($sua_conexao, $sql);
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$qtd = $data['TOTAL'];

if($qtd > 2) 
    die("Não é permitido cadastrar 3 reservas na mesma semana");
    // Aqui trate da melhor forma que ficar conveniente para a sua aplicação
```

Links úteis:

[COUNT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_count.asp)

[Pegar o primeiro e último dia da semana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541466/getting-first-last-date-of-the-week/8541741)

*Espero ter ajudado.*

Comment: Olhando sua solução acredito que $qtde, vai trazer quantidade de registro um, por que na query você está utilizando o COUNT(*), que vai trazer o total de registro em uma única linha, tem certeza que isso funciona, você testou?

Comment: @RaphaelGodoi muito boa sua observação e você está certo, editei a resposta.. Grato!

Comment: Agora que a resposta está editada, poderiam reconsiderar os downvotes ?

Comment: Cara muito obrigado mesmo, antes de postar minha dúvida aqui era essa lógica que eu tinha em mente, mas eu não sabia pegar a segunda-feira passada e o próximo sábado a data que o usuário deseja utilizar a reserva para poder jogar em uma query e comparar com o between a quantidade de reserva entre as duas datas, achei que era muito complicado, mas graças a vocês aprendi, executei, deu certo, vou poder utilizar em aplicações futuras e essa resposta vai poder ajudar muitos outros desenvolvedores. Obrigado mesmo, abraço

Answer (score 1):

Acho que é bem tranquilo resolver seu problema, primeiro com base no dia em que a pessoa estiver realizando a reserva você terá que saber qual é o primeiro e o último dia da semana atual, para isso utilize o código a baixo:

```
$semana_atual           = date('w');
$primeirodia_semanatual = date('Y-d-m', strtotime('-'.$semana_atual.' days'));
$ultimodia_semanaatual  = date('Y-d-m', strtotime('+'.(6-$semana_atual).' days'));

echo 'Primeiro dia Semana Atual: '.$primeirodia_semanatual;
echo '<br/>';
echo 'Último dia Semana Atual: '.$ultimodia_semanaatual;
```

OBS: coloquei a impressão das variáveis só para você entender a lógica.

Após determinar o primeiro dia e o último dia da semana atual, basta utilizar as datas/variáveis em uma query, para verificar quantas reservas foram realizadas naquela semana, por quem está tentando reservar, pelo que eu entendi o professor.

```
select count(*)
  from agend_reservas
  where reserva_para_data between '$primeirodia_semanatual'
                              and '$ultimodia_semanaatual'
    and reservado_para = '$login_de_quem_esta_reservando'
```

Se o resultado do `count(*)` for maior do que 3, significa que o professor já reservou 3x na semana atual :), ou seja, não pode reservar mais na semana, terá que esperar a semana seguinte.

Answer (score -1):

voce poderia adicionar duas colunas booleanas `primeira_reserva` e `segunda_reserva` na tabela. Quando alguem faz a reserva, ele verifica se a coluna `primeira_reserva` é verdaderia.

Caso seja falsa, ele realiza a reserva e marca a coluna como verdadeira. 
Caso a coluna `primeira_reserva` seja verdadeira, ele checa se a coluna
`segunda_reserva` é verdadeira.

Caso seja falsa, ele realiza a reserva e marca a coluna como verdadeira. 
Caso a coluna `segunda_reserva` seja verdadeira, ele simplesmente barra a reserva.

Desta maneira, ninguém conseguira cadastrar mais de 2 vezes na semana.

Daí basta programar a aplicação pra marcar essas duas colunas como falsas semanalmente. :)

Comment: Entendi, mas como eu faria basicamente para marcar a coluna como falsa semanalmente?

Comment: Você pode configurar seu servidor pra fazer isso automaticamente para ti: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26112/como-fazer-um-script-executar-automaticamente

Comment: Obrigado amigo, vou testar e dou retorno

Comment: Ok, boa sorte amigo! :)

Comment: A resposta do @8biT serviu mais ao meu caso mas mesmo assim obrigado, fico muito agradecido pela ajuda :D

Comment: de nada, um prazer ajudar! C: